# (Dygraphs JS) How can I disable the legend highlight for NaN points?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have a Dygraph.js with a moving legend that "snaps" to the nearest point. That's the desired behavior anyhow.

If I pass data in with **no** values (below), then I get the desired behavior. The highlight callback (I think) causes the legend to snap to the values at *(time_1, 1.5)* or *(time_4, 1.6)*, but ignores the time_2 and time_3:

```
time_1,1.5
time_2,
time_3,
time_4,1.6
```

But if I have data like this (with **NaN** values), then the legend actually snaps to the nonexistent points at time_2 and time_3, and it becomes difficult to highlight points in a crowded data set:

```
time_1,1.5
time_2,NaN
time_3,NaN
time_4,1.6
```

The thing is, I need to have support for *both* **no** values and **NaN** values in order to have control over how the data points are connected using `connectSeparatedPoints`. I want to **completely disable** the legend snapping / highlighting behavior for all points unless they have explicit, real non-NaN values.

Is `highlightCallback` / `unhighlightCallback` the correct way to implement this or would it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

A way to disable the legend, is to throw an exception in the first series formatter. Throwing an exception when the value of the second series is NaN will avoid legend snapping for such points.

This could be done using as first series formatter :

```
function(val, opts, seriesName, dygraph, row, col) {
    // raise an exception if the second series value is NaN 
    if (isNaN(dygraph.getValue(row, 1))) { 
        throw "disable legend for NaN" 
    } 
    return val; 
}
```

This snipnet show a short example of using this formatter :

```js
var data = "x,y\n"
           +"0,1.5\n"
           +"1,1.5\n"
           +"2,NaN\n"
           +"3,NaN\n"
           +"4,1.6\n"
           +"5,1.1\n";

new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"), data, {height:200,
        axes: {
          x: {
            valueFormatter: function(val, opts, seriesName, dygraph, row, col) { 
                if (isNaN(dygraph.getValue(row, 1))) { 
                  throw "disable legend for NaN" 
                } 
                return val; 
            }
          }
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.1.1/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
<div id="graph" />
```